# How do I center my text labels (showcasing in-group populations) vertically?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have the following plot, describing the distribution of academic credits depending on wether you live close to campus or some distance away:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
totdata%>%filter(status_registrerad=="registrerad")%>%
filter(ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2017"|ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2018"|ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2019")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(FLYTT, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y=PERC_CREDIT))+
geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()
```

I would like to add information on group sizes, so that the graph isn't misleading (the top group has only 14 members whilde the next one has 351...).

I guess I could add this information to the plot but...that would look messy I think. It would be way cleaner to showcase the group sizes in a separate plot, then I could call both of them with ggarrange.

My desired end result looks like this:

[image]

My objective is to create a plot containing a row of in-group populations from my first plot. In order to achieve this, I try recycling the code for the first plot while omitting the y value and adding geom_text.

```
totdata%>%filter(status_registrerad=="registrerad")%>%
filter(ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2017"|ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2018"|ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2019")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(FLYTT, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T)))+
geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..))
```

This gives somewhat reasonable results (though the background will have to be omitted, the font increased and the coordinates flipped), but the labels still have an y-value reflective of the in-group population.

[image]

I can't specify a different y value, since geom_text can't be specified with one. I have tried to specify `vjust="center"`, but to no avail.

How do I center my labels vertically while still having them showcase the in-group populations?

Excerpt of data (limited to 100 observations for readability)

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 
17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405, 17405), class = "Date"), 
    ADMISSIONROUND_ID = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("HT2012", "HT2013", "HT2014", "HT2015", 
    "HT2016", "HT2017", "HT2018", "HT2019"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), status_registrerad = c("registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", "registrerad", 
    "registrerad", "registrerad"), FLYTT = c("utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "Utflyttad Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "oklart", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", 
    "inflyttad eller boende Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", 
    "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan", "utflyttad från eller utanför Trollhättan"
    ), PERC_CREDIT = c(84.3333333333333, 89.3333333333333, 11, 
    89.3333333333333, 0, 89.3333333333333, 18.3333333333333, 
    40, 79.3333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 80.6666666666667, 
    60, 89.3333333333333, 0, 86, 71.6666666666667, 50, 20, 56.6666666666667, 
    10.3333333333333, 89.3333333333333, 27, 80, 82.6666666666667, 
    89.3333333333333, 81, 12, 81, 70, 75, 8.33333333333333, 19.3333333333333, 
    0, 35.6666666666667, 31.3333333333333, 84.3333333333333, 
    80, 68.6666666666667, 89.3333333333333, 31.3333333333333, 
    25.6666666666667, 24.6666666666667, 76.3333333333333, 76.3333333333333, 
    80, 81.6666666666667, 70, 0, 89.3333333333333, 81.3333333333333, 
    7, 0, 0.666666666666667, 75.6666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
    51.3333333333333, 90, 0, 47.6666666666667, 90, 56.3333333333333, 
    0, 81, 70, 89.3333333333333, 89.3333333333333, 35, 24, 89.3333333333333, 
    80, 0, 84.3333333333333, 41, 13.3333333333333, 55.6666666666667, 
    1.33333333333333, 50.6666666666667, 83.6666666666667, 85, 
    1.66666666666667, 65.6666666666667, 46.3333333333333, 70, 
    2.66666666666667, 53, 95, 50, 69.3333333333333, 76.3333333333333, 
    65.6666666666667, 72.6666666666667, 80, 0.666666666666667, 
    84.3333333333333, 64.3333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 50, 
    89.3333333333333, 84.3333333333333, 12.3333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17405, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:100)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: "I can't specify a different y value, since geom_text can't be specified with one"... ? I am not so sure about that?

Comment: Could you maybe try to boil down the question to the very core of the problem? Maybe use an inbuilt data set? This seems a lot of unnecessary code which makes it difficult to read the question, i.e. difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the solution you were looking for, but to my mind it is simpler and more elegant: change the name of your axis labels to include the number of cases:

```r
totdata2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(totdata, totdata$FLYTT), function(x)
{
    x$FLYTT <- paste0(x$FLYTT, "\n", "(n = ", length(x$FLYTT), ")"); x
}))
```

Now when you do your plot using `totdata2` you get this:

```
totdata2%>%filter(status_registrerad=="registrerad")%>%
filter(ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2017"|ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2018"|ADMISSIONROUND_ID=="HT2019")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(FLYTT, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y=PERC_CREDIT))+
geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()
```

[image]