# How do I reduce the space between geom_text labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have managed to construct the following plot, in which I use stripped down plot containing only geom_text labels to showcase in-group populations for another plot:

[image]

The distance between the geom_text labels is too large however, and the in-group populations are not "quite" vertically aligned with the groups they should be representing.

Is there a way to change this distance?

The code for the plot is as follows:

```
gymnasiegrov_utfall<-totdata%>%as_tibble() %>%
group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal))%>% 
ggplot(.) + 
geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
coord_flip() + 
facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)

gymnasiegrov_utfall_antal<-totdata%>% 
ggplot(aes(x=gymnasiegrov))+ 
geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),hjust="inward",y=1) + 
coord_flip()+
theme_invisible+
scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)+
scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL)

ggarrange(gymnasiegrov_utfall, gymnasiegrov_utfall_antal, ncol=2, widths = c(.85,.15))
```

subset of data with 1 observation for each category:

```
structure(list(gymnasiegrov = structure(c(1L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 
5L, 16L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 12L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 2L, 17L), .Label = c("Oklart", 
"friskoleprogram", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"specialutformat program", "Vård- och Omsorgsprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", 
"komvux", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "medieprogrammet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "naturbruksprogrammet", 
"estetiska programmet", "Barn- och Fritidsprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "Hotell- och Restaurang"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), totstatus_tri = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("pågående studier", 
"tidigt avbrott eller återbud", "sent avbrott"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -18L), groups = structure(list(
    gymnasiegrov = structure(1:18, .Label = c("Oklart", "friskoleprogram", 
    "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
    "Vård- och Omsorgsprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", "komvux", 
    "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "medieprogrammet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
    "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
    "naturbruksprogrammet", "estetiska programmet", "Barn- och Fritidsprogrammet", 
    "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
    "Hotell- och Restaurang"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
    .rows = list(1L, 17L, 8L, 16L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 
        11L, 13L, 10L, 14L, 7L, 18L, 15L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think it would be simpler to use the method I [described yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60164714/how-do-i-center-my-text-labels-showcasing-in-group-populations-vertically/60170411#60170411), but if you prefer the look of this method, then you can do something like this:

```r
library(ggpubr)

gymnasiegrov_utfall <- totdata %>% 
                       as_tibble() %>%
                       group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
                       summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
                       mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal)) %>% 
                       ggplot(.) + 
                       geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
                       coord_flip() + 
                       facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)

gymnasiegrov_utfall_antal <- totdata %>% 
                             ggplot(aes(x = gymnasiegrov)) + 
                             geom_text(stat = 'count', aes(label = ..count..), y = 1) + 
                             coord_flip() +
                             theme_pubclean() +
                             theme(strip.text = element_text(margin = margin(1, 0, 5, 0))) +
                             labs(y = "\n", x = "") +
                             scale_y_discrete(breaks = NULL) +
                             scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) +
                             facet_wrap(.~ "count")

ggarrange(gymnasiegrov_utfall, gymnasiegrov_utfall_antal, ncol = 2, widths = c(.85,.15))
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks! What I take away from this is: 

1)  faceting data changes the layout somehow and in this scenario, I'm best of comparing faceted data to other faceted data.

2) If i want to access the margins around the geom_text labels I can do that via strip.text?

Comment: Yes @Magnus, the major "hacks" were 1) making the second plot faceted. 2) adding an invisible y axis label to make the space equal at the bottom and 3) adjusting the margins of the strip.text to get it to match the first plot